# ListActivity: Buttons not firing off on onListItemClick

Tags: android, listview, button

Is there anyway to make the buttons work with onListItemClick ? My edit/delete buttons are in the actual list item.

As of right now, I am not able to click the list item or any of the buttons inside the list item. I set the focus of the buttons in the xml file as false, but that isn't working.

Any help is appreciated.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, final long id) {
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

  //button listeners
  edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    //On click function
    public void onClick(View view) {
      //Create the intent to start another activity
      Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), JournalEntry.class);
      startActivity(i);
      i.putExtra(JournalDB.KEY_ROWID, id);
      startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
    }
  });

  delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    //On click function
    public void onClick(View view) {
      journalDatabaseHelper.deleteEntry(id);
      Toast.makeText(JournalList.this, "Entry is being deleted...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      fillData();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please read up on how `Adapters` work.

Answer (score 1):

try to use below pasted code in onListItemClick function..

```
                    if (position== 1) {

                            Intent intent1 = new Intent(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    youractivity.class);

                            startActivity(intent1);

                        } else if (position== 2) {

                            Intent intent1 = new Intent(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    youractivity2.class);

                            startActivity(intent1);

                        }
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged in SO.

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Entry is being deleted...",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is this? What value does this "answer" give the OP and SO? Code only answers are discouraged in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Write your OnClick methods on Adapter's GetView() method.

Comment: I have a cursorAdapter..is that similar to an Adapter? Do you have an example of this code?